# How to do tensor transpose in C++

Tags: c++, eigen, transpose

I am porting Python code to C++ and I encountered this problem:
in Python to transpose a tensor of shape `(5, 3, 10)` into shape `(10, 5, 3)` I can use following function:

`np.transpose(tensor, (2, 0, 1))`

How can I do same operation in C++ either using standard library or any linear algebra library (like Eigen)

Comment: I recommend that you ask about Eigen specifically, since the C++ standard library does not have any linear algebra tools and asking for libraries is off-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transpose Tensor in Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815869/how-to-transpose-tensor-in-eigen)

Comment: @Avi, not really, that one is for two dimensional tensor (a matrix essentially), I am looking for a way to transpose three dimensional tensor.

Comment: And did you look up the documentation of `shuffle` here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html?